# IE and JavaScript (jQuery) problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have a page that has multiple tabs that toggle the display of hidden elements. 
It uses the following js:

```
$('document').ready(function() {

// Profile Tabs
$('ul.profile_tabs li').click(function(){
    var type = $(this).attr('type');

    $('.content-profile-title').css('display', 'none');
    $('.content-profile-display').css('display', 'none');

    $('#content-profile-title-'+type).css('display', 'block');
    $('#content-profile-display-'+type).css('display', 'block');

});
});
```

It grabs the type attribute of the ul element, and unhides the element with the corresponding ID.

Its working fine in FF and other browsers, just not IE!
I get the following console message: "Object doesn't support this property or method"
I've tried other methods like show/hide fadeIn/fadeOut..

Any help would be muchly apreciated :)

Comment: What line is throwing the exception?

Comment: What version of jQuery you are using? and did you try .css({display:"block"}); ?

Comment: It could be that IE is more strict about the attributes that can be used depending on the type of element. The `type` attribute is standard for the `input` elements, but not on `li` elements.

Comment: is it too much to ask which line gives you that error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use attributes to hold data.  But if you have to, try something like title which is available to most elements.

Comment: I tried using 'title', but it didn't work - although I don't think I was implementing it quite right. But that gave me an idea (based on Xint0 & AutoSponge's answers), I used the ID attribute instead of 'type', and it works fine now.

Thanks all!